# Comparing same serialized matplotlib plots in base64 yields false. How do i compare them properly using only serialized data?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, serialization

I'm serializing matplotlib plots, and when I go to compare them they always yield False, even when plots are the same. I want to be able to check if two plots are the same using serialized data. How do I do this properly?

Here is my code:

```
from binascii import b2a_base64
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
b0=b2a_base64(buf.getvalue()).decode()

plt.plot(range(10))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
b1=b2a_base64(buf.getvalue()).decode()

print(b0==b1)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing an image with one line in it with an image with two lines in it. Make sure to compare things that are supposed to be equal.

```
from binascii import b2a_base64
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
b0=b2a_base64(buf.getvalue()).decode()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
b1=b2a_base64(buf.getvalue()).decode()

print(b0==b1)
```

would work. Equally,

```
from binascii import b2a_base64
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot(range(10))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
b0=b2a_base64(buf.getvalue()).decode()

plt.close()

plt.plot(range(10))
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
b1=b2a_base64(buf.getvalue()).decode()

print(b0==b1)
```