# Is it possible to get the json value of a matplotlib object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, compare

I'm working on code generation with deep learning. I have a code (the ground truth) using `matplotlib` to plot a figure. My trained neural network will generate too a code to plot the figure. I would like to compare automatically both plot (it is not clever to compare the code because two different codes could return the same result).

I could compare both images but it is not convenient, is it possible to compare two plot objects with a boolean response?

For example, i have the following ground truth:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(1, 6):
    ax.plot(x, i*x + x, label='$y={i}x + {i}$'.format(i=i))
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

And this generated code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt1
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig, ax = plt1.subplots()
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
for i in range(1, 6):
    ax.plot(x, i*x + x, label='$y={i}x + {i}$'.format(i=i))
plt1.show()
```

Both code give the same plot with one swapping line, i would like to test something like:

```
plt == plt1
>> True
```

Comment: Could you add a more concrete example of what you need? What do you mean by "a matplotlib object"?  `plt` is usually used as a shortcut for matplotlib's pyplot library.

Comment: I edited my post to give you the context and more precision

Comment: Note that `plt` and `plt1` are equal, as they both indicate the same pyplot library.  Maybe you could save the plot to an image and then check whether the images are identical?

Comment: It was my idea at the beginning but it is not really convenient, it is not possible to do it on the fly?

Comment: See e.g. [Comparing same serialized matplotlib plots in base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779919/comparing-same-serialized-matplotlib-plots-in-base64-yields-false-how-do-i-comp) or the [testing API](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/testing_api.html)